# Showing complete value while you're typing in input form (html)(jinja2)

Tags: python, html, flask, input, jinja2

A bit like autocomplete, but instead of cookies, I'm trying to use this database called `contacts` to retrieve likely values and this database is managed by python/flask.
I'm trying to make it work like...

1) As you type 'bana'

2) It shows values passed from python (something like 'banana' and 'bananas') below the input form.

```
<form action='/sendmail' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='email' placeholder="To"
    ...
    <input type='submit' value='send'>
</form>
```

Assuming the name of a passed list containing related values is `likelyValue`, how should I incorporate `likelyValue` into this html file? I use jinja2 template but I can adjust code once I know how original html deals with it.

Comment: I think Flask-Admin does something like that, in the create and edit forms? You could have a look at the source on github.

Comment: Maybe this https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/    ?